# jquery - persist show after page reload

Tags: jquery

I have 3 T/F questions that show up as checkboxes on my webpage. The third question is hidden until the user checks the first two checkboxes. If the user checks the third checkbox as well, a new section of questions is shown. Here is the jquery that does this successfully.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_q1, #id_q2").click(function () {
                if ($("#id_q1").is(':checked') == true && $("#id_q2").is(':checked') == true) {
                    $(".question-hide").show();
                        $("#id_q3").click(function () {
                            if ($("#id_q3").is(':checked') == true ) {
                                $("#questions-hide").show();
                            } else {
                                $("#questions-hide").hide();
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    $(".question-hide").hide();
                    $("#questions-hide").hide();
                    $('#id_q3').attr('checked', false); 
                }
```

This page contains a submit button that creates an object if the form is valid (I'm doing this in django). It displays an error message if the required elements of the form aren't filled out. I would like the hidden sections to remain shown upon if they were initially shown. Right now the hidden sections remain hidden even if the three boxes are checked when the page is reloaded.

How can I obtain this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event instead, and trigger the handler when the page loads:

```
$("#id_q1, #id_q2").change(function () {
    //...
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I tried this, and the first two checkboxes end up initially checked upon reload, regardless of their initial status.

Comment: Edited answer - try the `change` event instead.

Comment: Hm, change prevents the hidden checkbox from showing when the first two checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tqjk5tva/. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle?